# MySQL Insert names from array into table A that don't exist in either B or C

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array of names to insert into table A for processing, but I only want to insert records from the array that don't exist in either table B or C

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: This is not a spoon feeding site.  What specific thing are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo code answer to your clear text question:

One way if solving your problem would be to first import the complete array into a temporary table `tmp`. Then you could run an insert command like

```
insert into a
select * from tmp 
where id not in (
  select id from b union all 
  select id from c
)
```

This simplified command assumes that you have the same columns in your array and tables a, b and c. You will have to adjust it to fit your purposes. After the insert just drop the temp table.